# Cancellation on unsubscribe only if observable hasn't completed

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an observable for which I would want to call cancellation (teardown) logic when subscriber unsubscribes from it but only if the source observable haven't completed yet (or failed) by itself.

The built-in `finalize` operator lets to register custom callback when `unsubscribe` occurs but it being called whenever the unsubscription was caused by subscriber or completion of the source observable.

I implemented the this helper function:

```js
function withCancellation(source, onCancel) {
  return new Observable(subscriber => {
    let completed = false;

    const cancellable = source.pipe(
      tap({
        error: () => { completed = true; },
        complete: () => { completed = true; },
      })
    );

    const subscription = cancellable.subscribe(subscriber);
    subscription.add(() => { if (!completed) onCancel(); });

    return subscription;
  });
}
```

Which I can use the following way:

```js
const sourceStream = startJob(jobId); // returns source observable
const cancellableStream = withCancellation(sourceStream, () => stopJob(jobId));
```

Is there any more concise way to achieve the same using any built-in primitives?

Comment: You're right, there's no way to do it with just `finalize`. There used to be an issue on RxJS GitHub https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2823. Some time ago I implemented it myself as well https://github.com/martinsik/rxjs-extra/blob/master/src/operators/finalizeWithReason.ts.

Comment: well, it's not exactly what you wanted to do but it's close :).